# Running the same code, old computers are as fast as new ones, is that true?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I've been learning about parallel programming in c++ and I came across [materials](https://ppc.cs.aalto.fi/) from a university. In the lecture they stated :

"With old code, a computer from 2021 is not any faster than a computer from 2000. In this course, we will learn how to write new code that is designed with modern computers in mind." [LINK](https://ppc.cs.aalto.fi/ch1/)

Waiting for answers from the professor, I thought to post my questions here.

Is that true? and in what conditions ? what do they mean by old code? sequential code?

In the lecture, they talk about the clock speed of the CPU and they mentioned that it hasn't been changed since the 2000s. Is that enough to say that an old computer is as fast as a new one?

Comment: If you ignore all the differences, they are the same.

Comment: Just look at process speeds.  2005-ish, you had a Pentium 4 with a 4GHZ clock.  Today, most processors are around there, so operations per second is basically the same.  The difference is back then, there was only one of those 4GHZ cores in the CPU.  Now there is many of them, and using them all at the same time can give you a multiplicative increase in performance.

Comment: I guess a better saying is that irrelevant of the code, if it's compiled with a compiler from 2000, it's likely to be slower than with modern compilers. That's because many compilers nowadays utilize vectorized instructions even in absolutely sequential code

Comment: Intel was selling ~1.50 GHz pentium 4s in late 2000. we've had a ~3x speedup in single core speed since then

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I would assume you can convince recent gcc to target the P4, and it wont use the vector instructions that didn't exist back then

Comment: Processors may have a similar clock speed but have many more cores and execute more instructions per clock cycle than they did in the past.

Comment: "a computer" includes the memory. RAM speeds have gotten faster; with a lower memory latency you'll get faster execution even with the same speed CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that true? and in what conditions ?

It is true that the clock speed of processors hasn't increased since ~2005 (and went down in the mean time).

That isn't to say that single core wall-clock performance hasn't improved. It hasn't been the case for long before then that each instruction took a single clock to process. There is a pipeline of instructions, and multiple calculations are "in-flight" at a time. A recent processor will take fewer cycles to execute the same instruction stream than an older processor.

Memory has also increased in speed, and processors have more on-die memory. Programs and data that didn't fit in the caches of a P4 might fit on a current-gen Core, and when they do have to fetch from RAM they are waiting less.

What is true is that a major improvement in processors since that era is the multiplication of cores on a single die, and using that performance is not as simple as "waiting for next year's faster processor"

Comment: "the main improvement in processors since that era is the multiplication of cores" is not really true. For example, on Intel processors, 
the PentiumM (2003) was able to do 1 float fuse-multiply-add (FMA) per cycle, IvyBridge (2012) was able to perform 2 float/cycles, SkylakeX (2017) reached 32 floats/cycle and IceLake (2019) reached 16 floats/cycle. This is a speed-up of 16~32 in less than 20 years. *SIMD matters a lot*. Branches can now be *predicted* in 7~14 times faster than on a P4 (2000).

Comment: @JérômeRichard so it is not true that CPUs from +2000 are the same as 2021 ones even in sequential processing!?

Comment: @JérômeRichard yes, there will be workloads where that is a bigger improvement. I've weakened that point

Comment: @Ja_cpp yes, I explained some of the other ways they are faster in my answer. It's also the case that if you were to take the old source code and use modern tools it would be faster still